# How to place a figure exactly where I would like to?

Tags: floats

I have downloaded the package `float` in order to help in placing figures where I would like them.  At the moment, 'All' figures are placed at the 'end' of document.

I have run the script '`float.dtx`.

Subsequently, the [H] option has been inserted as seen below example; however, nothing has changed and the figures still appear at the end of document.

Does any one have an idea as to what is needed to activate the `float` programs appropriately or as to how to implement them?

Thank you.

```
%%%%% Inserting figure %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{figure}[H] 
\begin{center}
 \maketitle {\bf Title}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Figure}
 \caption{Explanatory statement}
\label{}
 \end{center} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please provide a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: Welcome Anna, what is `\maketitle` supposed to do in the figure environment? It usually typesets the dcuments title including your name and the date.

Comment: Apart from that, the command `\bf` is obsolete and should be replaced by `\bfseries`. The `center` environment adds extra vertical space, that you most likely not want. You can replace it by `\centering`.

Comment: Did you put `\usepackage{float}` after `documentclass`?

Comment: @Johannes_B no:-)

Answer (score 4):

Your demand is against to basic rule of TeX/LaTeX: figures and tables (and similar object) should be in float environments that can be moved to place, where the best fit into the text ...

To achieve, what you like, is the simplest way not to use floats. Just put figure directly in text and for caption use `\captionof` from package `caption` or small package `captionof` when you like to use caption formatting facility of used document class:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{capt-of}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{My caption}
    \label{fig:mc-1}
\end{center}
See Fig.~\ref{fig:mc-1} ...
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `s/captionof/capt-of/` in the middle of the text ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the float package ?

First read about [figure placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/75098) and try with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp] 
  \centering
  \textbf{Your title}\\
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{fig}
  \caption{Explanatory statement \label{fig:fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that does not ensure that the figure is placed *exactly* here.

Comment: Yes, but the main problem here was I quote: "All' figures are placed at the 'end' of document", therefore it preferably not advised to use H ...

if 'exactly here' is needed then why use a floating env ? see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/75098

Comment: @neok `H` floats wil never go to the end of the document if `H` is defined. So the OP had not loaded the float package.